# Авторизация пользователей по лицу в андроид приложении

Tags: android, api, firebase

Моя задача, сделать андроид приложение с авторизацией по лицу. Предварительно я сделал обычную авторизацию по логину и паролю с помощью Firebase? чтобы в дальнейшем в профиле можно было добавить биометрию лица. Вопрос заключается в том, возможно ли сделать авторизацию по лицу через различные сервисы Firebase или же использовать сторонние сервисы, если сторонние то какие? В приоритете нейронные сети, но какие есть варианты, которые можно прикрутить как распознавалку и с помощью которого будет возможен вход в приложение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, в системе Android это встроенный функционал. Никаких сервисов использовать не нужно. У вас в системе есть хранилище ваших данных. Оно защищено довольно хорошо так как там хранятся ваши отпечатки например и данные сканера лица. Для того чтобы использовать данное хранилище нужно:

1. Добавить зависимость:

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'
   ```
2. Добавить в манифест разрешение:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
   ```
3. Будем использовать для вызова диалога например кнопку:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="30dp">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/touch_button"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@color/river_blue"
           android:stateListAnimator="@null"
           android:text="Biometric Login"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:textSize="16sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>

   </layout>
   ```
4. Добавляем необходимые переменные в класс активности:

   ```
   private static final String KEY_NAME = "KeyName";
   private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
   private static final String FORWARD_SLASH = "/";
   ```
5. В функции `onCreate()` добавляем эти строки:

   ```
   touchButton = findViewById(R.id.touch_button);
   touchButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> onTouchIdClick());
   displayBiometricButton();
   ```
6. Обрабатываем клик на кнопку:

   ```
   private void onTouchIdClick() {
       getBiometricPromptHandler().authenticate(getBiometricPrompt(), new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(getCipher()));
       // Please see the below mentioned note section.
       // getBiometricPromptHandler().authenticate(getBiometricPrompt());
   }
   ```
7. Проверяем доступно ли на устройстве хоть какие-то способы биометрической защиты:

   ```
    private boolean isBiometricCompatibleDevice() {
       if (getBiometricManager().canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Отображаем кнопку логина если есть какие-то средства биометрии:

   ```
   private void displayBiometricButton() {
       if (isBiometricCompatibleDevice()) {
           touchButton.setEnabled(false);
       } else {
           touchButton.setEnabled(true);
           generateSecretKey();
       }
   }
   ```
9. Получаем менеджер биометрического хранилища и генерируем ключ:

   ```
   private BiometricManager getBiometricManager() {
       return BiometricManager.from(this);
   }

   private void generateSecretKey() {
       KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
       KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
               KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
               .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
               .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
               .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
               .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(false)
               .build();
       try {
           keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                   KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       if (keyGenerator != null) {
           try {
               keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
           } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           keyGenerator.generateKey();
       }
   }

   private SecretKey getSecretKey() {
       KeyStore keyStore = null;
       Key secretKey = null;
       try {
           keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
       } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       if (keyStore != null) {
           try {
               keyStore.load(null);
           } catch (CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               secretKey = keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
           } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       return (SecretKey) secretKey;
   }
   ```
10. Подключаем шифровальщик и обрабатываем данные с считывателей:

    ```
    private Cipher getCipher() {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + FORWARD_SLASH
                    + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + FORWARD_SLASH
                    + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey());
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipher;
    }

    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo getBiometricPrompt() {
        return new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                .setSubtitle("Login with your biometric credential")
                .setNegativeButtonText("cancel")
                .setConfirmationRequired(false)
                .build();
    }

    private void onBiometricSuccess() {
        //Call the respective API on biometric success
        callLoginApi("userName", "password");
    }

    private BiometricPrompt getBiometricPromptHandler() {
        return new BiometricPrompt(this, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                        onBiometricSuccess();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    ```

Вот [документ](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd) где описано сенсоры для доступа к хранилищу. Подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738969/face-authentication-to-unlock-my-app-programmatically) и обсуждение. [Документация_1](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth), [документация_2](https://source.android.com/security/biometric) и [документация_3](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/face-authentication). [Туториал](https://bytefish.de/blog/face_detection_with_android/) по использованию распознавания по лицу.